# django nested serialization of many to many relationship having an intermediate table

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have seen a lot of posts on how to deserialize and serialize nested relationships of tables having a many to many relationship, but when an intermediate table is used in a many to many relationship I am not able to achieve deserialization.

This is because an intermediate table requires two foreign keys, one each from the two tables participating in the relation.

I have an **Order** model and a **Service** model which are in a many to many relationship via an **OrderItem** intermediate table.

I need to pass a JSON request like this:

```
{"service_time":"2015-11-14 10:00:51+0530",
  "address":"xyz",
   "items":[{"order": "1", "service_id":"4"},
               {"order":"1", "service_id":"5"}]
}
```

The "service_time" and "address" elements get saved in the **Order** table. Now the problem arises with the "items" JSON array. I pass the "service_id" (foreign key to the **Service** table) and I **need to pass "order" (foreign key to the Order table) too as it is a required field**. The problem is that the primary key of the **Order** table is not known when the request is sent(as the Order is also created as a part of the same request). How can I achieve deserialization in this scenario?

I tried something like this but it didn't work out.

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('items')
        orders = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item in items_data:
            #order = item['order']
            service = item['service']
            //Passing the Order object just created as the foreign key of OrderItem
            orderItem = OrderItem.objects.create(order=orders, service=service)
            orderItem.save()
        return orders

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.CharField(source="group.group_name")
    category = serializers.IntegerField(source="group.category_id")

    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ['id', 'service_name', 'price', 'special_price', 'service_time', 'group', 'category']

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    service_detail = ServiceSerializer(source="service", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
```

I get an error saying **'Service' object has no attribute 'order'**.

I know the **Service** model does not have an "order" attribute, but I am creating an **OrderItem** object, not a **Service** object.

Any suggestions will be helpful!

**Edit: Adding the models used**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUSES = [('PENDING', 'Pending'), ('PROCESSING', 'Processing'), ('COMPLETE', 'Complete'), ('CANCELED', 'Canceled')]
    PAYMENT_STATUSES = [('PENDING', 'Pending'), ('PAID', 'Paid'),]
    CANCEL_REASON = [('NO_SERVICE', 'No Service In Area'), ('NO_STYLIST', 'Stylist Not Available'), ('STYLIST_REFUSED', 'Stylist Refused After Accepting',), 
            ('CUSTOMER_UNREACHABLE', 'Customer Not Reachable'), ('CUSTOMER_CANCELED', 'Customer Canceled at Fisrt Call'), ('CUSTOMER_REFUSED', 'Customer Refused at Last Moment'), 
            ('DUPLICATE_ORDER', 'Duplicate Order'), ('MALE_CLIENT', 'Male Client'), ('CALLCENTER_DELAY', 'Delay/Error at Frontdesk')]
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True,)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, verbose_name="customer", related_name="ordersbycustomer")
    stylist = models.ForeignKey(Stylist, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="stylist", related_name="ordersbystylist")
    # TODO, Use timezone.now
    service_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    started_moving = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    service_start_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    service_end_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    reached_safely = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    sub_total = models.FloatField(default=0)
    discounts = models.FloatField(default=0)
    grand_total = models.FloatField(default=0)
    total_time = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=STATUSES, default='PENDING')
    payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=PAYMENT_STATUSES, default='PENDING')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Service, through='OrderItem')
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, null=True,  blank=True, related_name='+',  on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    amount_received = models.FloatField(default=0)
    send_sms = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    thru_app = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    referral_discount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    cancellation_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=CANCEL_REASON, null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.serial

    def _get_service_list(self):
        return ','.join(str(p.description) for p in self.items.all())

    service_list = property(_get_service_list)


class Service(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="services")
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    special_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    service_time = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=123)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.service_name, self.group)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    special_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    qty = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.service.service_name
```

**Edit2: Added the other related serializers.**

**One important thing I forgot to mention is that, the data gets saved in the DB, but the exception is still raised.**

Comment: Do you have a related_name ob your FK field? This is the name you should have as the filed in your serializer. It would also be helpful if we could see the models.

Comment: Why does related_name matter here? A little more explanation will help

Comment: I think I didn't understand your problem first time round. It's difficult to understand your problem because you models are not described in your question. I think you should be doing something like service = Service.objects.create(**your_args)

Comment: Yes what you said would be correct if I do not use an intermediate table for the m2m relationship. Now that there is an intermediate table called "OrderItem", why should I call Service.objects.create? I should be creating an entry in the intermediate OrderItem table right?

Comment: According to this link, you cannot create a "Service" object if there is an intermediate table explicitly specified. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: Could you add all related model to your question, please?

Comment: Please add all fields of your models because we can't help you if you don't have all variables. We need them to exclude some errors and search in the right direction. I think I found the error but, i have to be sure.

Comment: Added all the model fields for completeness

Comment: add you ItemSerializer too and other serializer linked to, please. Sorry man, but we need everything to have a the global context and understand where does the problem com from :)

Comment: added  the related serializers. Hope this should be complete!